# VBA Excel paste row in different sheet after finding a value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use below-mentioned piece of VBA code, but it gives me an error saying: PasteSpecial methond of Range class failed

```
pastesheet.Range("C13:C300").Find(what:=cntr, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

pastesheet is the destination sheet in which I want to find find cntr (a value from a different sheet in a different workbook).
After that I want to replace the row in which cntr is found with an entire new row which is already copied earlier.

Could someone please assist to make this work?

Comment: Seems fine to me, what are you trying to paste?

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if the value has been found. If no value is found, the action is performed anyway causing the error.

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = pastesheet.Range("C13:C300").Find(what:=cntr, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Offset(0, -2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```